# ViewModel returns a default value of 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I am working on  a real estate management information system. I have this ViewModel:

```
public class UnitViewModel
{

    public IEnumerable<HouseModel> HouseModels { get; set; }
    public int SelectedModelID { get; set; }

    public int Block { get; set; }
    public int FromLot { get; set; }
    public int ToLot { get; set; }

    public double LotArea { get; set; }
    public double FloorArea { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Site> Sites { get; set; }
    public int SelectedSiteID { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }

}
```

And I use it in this controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        UnitViewModel unitVM = new UnitViewModel();
        unitVM.HouseModels = db.HouseModels.ToList();
        unitVM.Sites = db.Sites.ToList();
        return View(unitVM);
    }
```

However, when I run the app, it gives me this output.

[image]

Is there a way to remove those 0 default values? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could make the properties `nullable` (if the initial value is `null` then nothing will be displayed in the textbox). You might also want to add the `[Required]` attribute if they are required

Comment: This might sound contradicting, but can I add a required attribute in nullable types? Thanks

Comment: Yes of course you can - `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the block")] public int? Block { get; set; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the Block property type from `Int` to **Nullable int**

```
public class UnitViewModel
{    
    public IEnumerable<HouseModel> HouseModels { get; set; }
    public int SelectedModelID { get; set; }

    public int? Block { get; set; }

    // Other properties goes here
}
```

Since Block is a nullable int, It is always a good idea to do a null checking before accessing it and calling any methods on that.

```
[Httppost]
public ActionResult Create(UnitViewModel model)
{
  if(model.Block!=null)
  {
     int blockValue= model.Block.Value;
     // do something now
  }
  // to do : Do something and return something
}
```

You can use data annotations on this nullable property for your validations.

```
public class UnitViewModel
{    
    [Required]
    public int? Block { get; set; }

    // Other properties goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that one. However, can I add a data annotation for that kind of property? 'Cause I have a constraint where a unit cannot be created without a block and lot. @Shyju

Comment: @freedomn-m, what's a fouq?  Google isn't helping me

Comment: Yes @Cyval You can have a Required attribute on this property to help you with validation.

Comment: Thanks so much, and happy 70k reputation. :D

Comment: Thanks & Welcome : ) You all are awesome ;)

Comment: @freedomn-m, ah, okay.  `fouc` is something I know.  But your `fouq` didn't make sense, now I see you just made a typo.  Thanks for clearing that up.